# Runtime link error: The procedure entry point glewInit@0 could not be located

Tags: c++, opengl, linker, mingw, glew

I'm just getting started using GLEW on Windows with MinGW. I can compile the program successfully (`glew.h` and `libglew.a` are in the proper place within MinGW), however executing my program throws the above error. `glew32.dll` is present in the same directory as the executable, and I've found and attempted various solutions to my problem. However, my problem seems to be different to others - the error message is complaining that `glewInit` cannot be found *in the executable itself* as opposed to `glew32.dll`. I haven't managed to find anything about this on Google.

Here's the error:

[image]

As you can see, it's not complaining about not being able to find the glew method in a DLL, **but in the program file itself**. I feel I am linking the executable incorrectly, but I have very little experience with fixing this kind of error.

Here's my Makefile:

```
EXEC      = test1.exe
SRC_FILES = test1.cpp wavefront.cpp

CXX = g++
CC = $(CXX)

DEBUG_LEVEL     = -g
EXTRA_CCFLAGS   = -Wall
CXXFLAGS        = $(DEBUG_LEVEL) $(EXTRA_CCFLAGS)
CCFLAGS         = $(CXXFLAGS)

CPPFLAGS        = -I.

LDFLAGS         = -L"/cygdrive/c/MinGW/lib"
LDLIBS          = -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system -lopengl32 -lglu32 -lglew32

O_FILES         = $(SRC_FILES:.cpp=.o)

all: .FORCE

.FORCE: compile link

compile:
    $(CXX) -c $(SRC_FILES)

link: 
    $(CXX) $(O_FILES) -o $(EXEC) $(LDFLAGS) $(LDLIBS)

clean:
    $(RM) $(O_FILES) *.exe *.rpo
```

Comment: Did you build glew32 using mingw yourself or is this from a prebuilt binary?

Comment: This is from a pre-built binary. I attempted to build GLEW myself, however I can't install the X11 dev dependencies it requires. I think I've managed to get it working by compiling with `glew32s.lib` (static lib), however

Comment: Why would it need `X11` on a windows platform? o.O

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error in your title and in your diagram are completely different. The first error, in your title is the decorated DLL export name and the second one is for a `__stdcall` function. For whatever reason, the import stub seems to be trying to resolve the function address from your application rather than the DLL.

Perhaps you did not properly define `dllexport` behavior when you built your DLL or `dllimport` when linking against it? GLEW uses the pre-processor definition: `GLEW_BUILD` for this purpose.

In any event, using the static linking glew library will definitely solve this issue, though I cannot say why it is happening for sure.

Link against `glew32s` and add `-DGLEW_STATIC` to your Makefile.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, they were both supposed to read what the title correctly shows

Comment: @Bojangles: Ah, here's the interesting thing though... `glewInit (...)` is usually a `__stdcall` function, which means the decorated name should be `_glewInit@0`. I think somewhere along the lines the calling convention when the DLL was compiled and the calling convention when you built your program changed. You might try re-defining `GLEWAPI` as `extern __declspec(dllimport) __stdcall`. But I think maybe you forgot an underscore in the title of your question.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I linked against `glew32s.lib` provided in the Windows binary download from the GLEW site and that works fine